# Can i see Smart Target Experiments in Google Analytics Tool?

Tags: smarttarget, experiment

I am working on Experiments,i have set up Google Analytics and Created Experiments for my Home Page mentioned in SDL Documentation. In my DD4T Web Application i can see all the Variants Which i Created for my Home Page but in CME i am not getting any Statistics (View/Conversions) :
[image]

I have few questions regarding Experiments:

1 : Can i See my Experiments in Google Analytics ? (As i am Seeing Nothing in Experiment Tab in Google Analytics)

2 : I am Seeing all the Variants in my Home Page, But as mentioned in SDL Documentation that "Content Variants are displayed randomly to Web site visitors within a given time frame" but I don't see any Setting to Configure the Time Frame for a particular Variant as i am seeing both the Variants simultaneously.

As per my Understanding Google Analytics Experiments works for Two or More Experience URL's, So that based on Statistics for each URL one can decide the Winning URL and can put it on live. So how Our Tridion Experiments works With Google Experiments As we have only one single Tridion page which are displaying Two variant simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- No, the experiments in SmartTarget are somehow the same idea as the experiments in Google Analytics, but are not the same, so the experiments you may set in SmartTarget are not going to be shown in Google Analytics as Experiments. (I think that the SmartTarget experiments are located in Google Analytics as Events, but I'm no GA expert).

If you don't see any conversion in your defined experiment, maybe there is a problem with the experiment, or you may have missed something. The way Experiments work is as follows:

- include diferent content in a region controlled by smarttarget. In this content it has to be included a link to test the conversions.
- smarttarget changes the link to an intermediate link (/redirect/), so if someone clicks the link, it redirects to the intermediate link (servlet), this servlet redirects to your original link, but register the redirection in google analytics as a variant conversion
- so the results in the experiment graphics is the difference between the times that component is displayed, and the times is displayed and followed the link

If you are clicking the link and see no conversions of the experiment, there may be a problem with the setup.

2- SmartTarget display or choose the content to display randomly, the Time Frame that is commented in the documentation refers to the expiration of the user cookies; if the session is the same for a given user, the content displayed is the same as it is saved in the cookies. If you delete the cookies, you may have a different content randomly, and it is counted as a new "view event". The way the item is chosen is totally random:

```
int chosen = new Random().nextInt(maximum);
```

beeing "`maximum`" the number of items on the experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, We are not using any redirection in our site yet. So i opened IIS and created one redirect directory In my Web site. In my application web.config i added  <add name="Tridion.SmartTarget.Analytics.TrackingRedirect" path="C:\NeelNew\Neel\TietoGadget\TietoGadget\Redirect\" verb="GET" type="Tridion.SmartTarget.Analytics.TrackingRedirect" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />. I also added third party jars and smart target analytics jar in my application lib.  Should i see anything in Redirect Folder ?

Comment: No, "redirect" folder must exist but is going to be empty. In your published pages you must see the change in the links of your components. If you include in your component presentation a link, say <a href="http://x.y">link text</a> then if you see the source code of the final page, the link must be converted to something like <a href="/redirect?url=http://x.y.....">link text</a>.

Comment: Thanks, Although I don't see any converted link , It is same as in my code. So might be a issue with my redirect directory.

Comment: Just a Reminder this is my DD4T Web Application. How Smart Target changes the link to intermediate link?

Comment: what part take care of changing href url from "x.y" to "/redirect?url=x.y", just to understand whether i need to republish my experiment content or check related smart target configs?

Comment: The change of the url is made in the "AnalyticsManager" class with the url that is configured in the Analytics node of the "smarttarget_conf.xml". It's in the java part, that it's included even in the .NET installation.